# open <TAB> opening finder window

Tags: terminal, finder, zsh

I use zsh. For some reason, with zsh, when I type `open <TAB>` (which should list the files to autocompletion), it opens Finder in the current folder.

I don't have anything aliased for that. I didn't change any config recently. I don't have any idea about why this is happening. Bash works, though.

Any ideas on how can I fix or debug that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

`which open` always shown `/usr/bin/open`, but `which _open` showed me this:

```
_open() {
   if [ "$(uname -s)" = "Darwin" ]; then
     open "$1" 2> /dev/null
   else
     xdg-open "$1" &> /dev/null
   fi
 }
```

Which was declared by a plugin that I was using.

Functions prefixed with `_` are used as autocompletion functions, and that's why my `open` autocompletion was broken.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this issue, so it should not happen by default. TAB works as expected in `zsh` (as in `bash`). What version of OSX are you using? This is in a standard terminal window right? Do you have something in your `.zshrc` file relating to *custom completion settings*?

Try deleting your .zshrc file and run the `zsh` shell again,

```
mv .zshrc .zshrc.old
zsh
```

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug mode in ZSH using the -vx flags.

Open up terminal, and create a new ZSH instance:

```
zsh -vx
```

Then, try your

```
open <tab>
```

It should print out everything it's trying to match on, and any processing it's doing. Might give you a clue as to which setting is influencing this behaviour. I can't replicate on mine.